# How to iterate products on for to get specific DOM elements with foreach on PHP 7

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, domdocument

I really don't know what's happening that I'm cannot iterate this object of data. The problem is that I always print the same object, but if I print a separate values, it's be there.

Each product has a hidden inputs and I'm reading it with `DomDocument` PHP library.

```
<input class="productName" id="03MJRUXE" type="hidden" value="Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê">
<input class="productId" id="03MJRUXE" type="hidden" value="03MJRUXE">
<input class="productPrice" id="03MJRUXE" type="hidden" value="69.99">
<input class="productCategory" id="03MJRUXE" type="hidden" value="Polos">
<input class="productBrand" id="03MJRUXE" type="hidden" value="Business">
```

Each product has a `product-info` div and each one product print the own DOMElement below:

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => input
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => input
    [nodeValue] => 
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => input
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 
)
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => input
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => input
    [nodeValue] => 
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => input
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 
)

...
```

I'll let a screenshot below:

[image]

And my function that iterate this elements is below:

```
/**
 * Extract info of the inputs.
 *
 * @param DOMNodeList $elements
 * @param DOMNodeList $qtdeProducts
 * @return array
 */
private function extractInfoByInputs($elements, $qtdeProducts)
{
    $productInputs = [];
    $arrKeysList = [
        'productName',
        'productId',
        'productPrice',
        'productCategory',
        'productBrand'
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $qtdeProducts->length; $i++) {
        /**
         * @var int $k
         * @var DOMElement $element
         */
        $arrProducts = [];
        $loop = 0;
        foreach ($elements as $k => $element) {
            $class = $element->getAttribute('class');
            if (!in_array($class, $arrKeysList)) {
                unset($elements[$k]);
            } else {

                print_r($element);

                if ($loop >= sizeof($arrKeysList))
                    continue;

                $class = $element->getAttribute('class');
                $value = $element->getAttribute('value');

                $arrProducts[$loop] = [$class => $value];
                $loop++;

                /*foreach ($arrKeysList as $y => $kItem) {
                    if ($class === $kItem) {

                        $arrData[$y] = [$class => $value];
                        $arrProducts[$loop] = $arrData[$y];
                    }
                }*/

                //$productInputs[$i] = $arrProducts;
                //$loop++;
            }
        }

        $productInputs[$i] = $arrProducts;
    }

    print_r($productInputs);

    return $productInputs;
}
```

The wrong output is below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03MJRUXE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 69.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03MJRUXE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 69.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03MJRUXE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 69.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03MJRUXE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 69.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )
```

### Update

I updated the PHP code and I set a screenshot also.

Please, someone can help me with that?

Comment: Show more of your html file (in particular show several products with the parent nodes);

Comment: ALSO What would be the right output

Comment: I update the code now. Thank's for your interest to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question!

Sometimes it's good to erase everything and start over.

- First, I convert DOMNodeList to array of DOMElement with for loop.
- Second, I make a foreach loop of list of attribute's names and other foreach loop of elements converted.

The code of solution is below:

```
/**
 * Extract info of the inputs.
 *
 * @param DOMNodeList $elements
 * @return array
 */
private function extractInfoByInputs($elements)
{
    $arrKeysList = [
        'productName',
        'productId',
        'productPrice',
        'productCategory',
        'productBrand'
    ];

    $arrayElements = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $elements->length; $i++) {
        $item = $elements->item($i);
        $class = $item->getAttribute('class');

        if (in_array($class, $arrKeysList))
            $arrayElements[] = $item;
    }

    $arrayAttrs = [];
    foreach ($arrKeysList as $y => $kItem) {
        $loop = 0;
        /**
         * @var int $k
         * @var DOMElement $element
         */
        foreach ($arrayElements as $k => $element) {
            $class = $element->getAttribute('class');
            $value = $element->getAttribute('value');

            if ($class === $kItem) {
                $arrayAttrs[$loop][$y] = [$class => $value];

                $loop++;
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($arrayAttrs);

    return $arrayAttrs;
}
```

And the output is below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03MJRUXE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 69.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Listrada
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03XZAMSE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 59.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Tie Dye
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 03TBNCME
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productPrice] => 99.99
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [productCategory] => Polos
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [productBrand] => Business
                )

        )

        etc...
```

#### One observation about those keys

There is many keys in out loop.

Actually it's grouped by key, but it's better to group by input name/class and your value.

So, one little modification...

- Before:

  `$arrayAttrs[$loop][$y] = [$class => $value];`
- And now:

  `$arrayAttrs[$loop][$class] = $value;`

... and that's it! Better output is below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Flamê
            [productId] => 03MJRUXE
            [productPrice] => 69.99
            [productCategory] => Polos
            [productBrand] => Business
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Listrada
            [productId] => 03XZAMSE
            [productPrice] => 59.99
            [productCategory] => Polos
            [productBrand] => Business
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [productName] => Camisa Polo Masculina Tie Dye
            [productId] => 03TBNCME
            [productPrice] => 99.99
            [productCategory] => Polos
            [productBrand] => Business
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [productName] => Camisa Masculina Slim
            [productId] => H2EUSE01E
            [productPrice] => 119.99
            [productCategory] => Camisas
            [productBrand] => Business
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [productName] => Camiseta Masculina Alongada
            [productId] => 4E6QWBDE
            [productPrice] => 49.99
            [productCategory] => Camisetas
            [productBrand] => Business
        )

    [5] => ...
```

I hope to help someone else by solving this question.